# Parse Installation object ACL

Tags: android, parse-platform

I get automatic user to set an ACL on my Installation object

```
Parse.initialize(this, AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();

ParseACL mACL = new ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().setACL(mACL);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

it creates right the Installation but then i receive error

> com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: object not found for update

on update channels or columns. Why?

**UPDATE**
Tried with Cloud Code

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
console.log("user"+request.user);
if (request.user) {
        request.object.set('user', request.user);
    } else {
   request.object.unset('user');
}
response.success();
```

});

I got "usernull" on console and error

> com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: at least one ID field (installationId,deviceToken) must be specified in this operation

Answer (score 0):

You can not update your Installation when you set Parse Security `(ParseACL)`

You can update record with Master Key but i haven't try it

This what docs says [link](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseACL.html)

> A ParseACL is used to control which users can access or modify a
>   particular object. Each ParseObject can have its own ParseACL. You can
>   grant read and write permissions separately to specific users, to
>   groups of users that belong to roles, or you can grant permissions to
>   "the public" so that, for example, any user could read a particular
>   object but only a particular set of users could write to that object.

Comment: Why with MasterKey if I have my automatic user, or isnt automatic user a valid user?